# markov process with extra boundary

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

In a markov process a random walker has to reach N (absorbing boundary) from $x_o$ on a $[0,N]$ lattice, where $0$ is the reflecting boundary. To find the first exit time of the random walker via N, i use the following equation ($mean = 0$)
$$ \frac{d^2T}{dx^2} = -\frac{2}{D} $$
with boundary and initial conditions as  $$ 1) T|_{x=N} = 0   \ \ \  2) \frac{dT}{dx} |_{x=0} = 0 $$
but now I have a trap in between and it acts as a temporary absorbing point. So  whenever the random walker visits the trap it gets absorbed by it and after $\tau$ times in trap, the random walker will be released again on the lattice. The process stops when random walker hits the absorbing boundary,N.

So is there way to solve it for the first exit time?

Thank you.

Comment: When searching for `Simple random walk with one reflecting barrier'  I stumbled across [these notes](http://www2.math.uu.se/~sea/kurser/stokprocmn1/slumpvandring_eng.pdf). See e.g. Section 3.3 and Example 4.

Comment: These [slides](http://www.maths.dur.ac.uk/users/andrew.wade/talk/NHRW13.pdf) and the references therein are also useful.

Comment: Is the model a random walk in discrete time on a discrete lattice?

Comment: @Did yes yes it is...

Comment: If $x$ is discrete, what is $d^2T/dx^2$?

Comment: $ \frac{d^2T}{dx^2} = -\frac{2}{D} $ rite?